# Quote issue in HTML, Javascript, .innerHTML, switch and case

Tags: javascript, html

I'm modifying a websense block page to include a few functions based on a variable: $*WS_BLOCKREASON*$. I know the potential output of this variable, and I want to have a specific function for.

The issue is that the page is not passing even the default case to the '<'div'>' contents. Essentially I need the contents of the `<div id="helpDiv">` to be a whole set of text including the button. Script below:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Access to this site is blocked</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/en/Custom/master.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/en/Default/master.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/en/Default/base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/en/Custom/security.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 130px;
           height: 70px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<!--[if lt IE 7]> <div style="width: 725px; height: 381px;"> <![endif] -->
        <img alt="BHI" class="style1" 
            src="/en/Custom/other.gif" /><br />
        <br />
        <br />
<div style="border: 1px solid #285EA6;width: 99.5%; max-width: 915px; overflow: hidden; margin-left: 1px; background-color: #EEF2F7;">
    <iframe src="$*WS_BLOCKMESSAGE_PAGE*$*WS_SESSIONID*$" title="BHI_BLOCK" 
        name="ws_block" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
        style="width:100%; height: 200px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    </iframe>
<hr />
    <!-- onload=function() possible fix -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var blockReason=$*WS_BLOCKREASON*$;

    switch (blockReason)
        {
        case 'This Websense category is filtered: <b>Uncategorized</b>.':
            document.getElementById('helpDiv').innerHTML='<p style="margin-left: 10px">Help:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Submit UNCATEGORIZED website to Websense" onClick="parent.location=\'mailto:suggest@websense.com?subject=Uncategorized Website&body=Please review and correctly categorize the website that is listed below:%0A%0A' + $*WS_URL*$ + '%0A%0AThank you.\'"></p>\
            <hr />\
            <p style="margin-left: 64px">Clicking on the above button will open your mail client to send an e-mail to Websense for recategorization of the above site.</p>\
            <p style="margin-left: 64px">You will receive a confirmation e-mail and a case number from Websense indicating your request is proccessing.</p>\
            <p style="margin-left: 64px">Please note the response time for your request will vary. Allow to three to four (3-4) hours for updates to take effect once approved.</p>\
            <p style="margin-left: 64px">If you have any questions, please contact SOLV at <a href=tel:+18772222222>+1 877 2222222<a/> or <a href=http://solv:8093/CAisd/pdmweb.exe?OP=JUST_GRONK_IT+HTMPL=about.htmpl target="_blank">this link.</a></p>';
        break;

        case 'This Websense category is filtered: <b>Parked Domain</b>.':
            document.getElementById('helpDiv').innerHTML='<p>Parked domain</p>';
        break;

        default:
            document.getElementById('helpDiv').innerHTML='<p>No Block message help.</p>';
        }
    </script>
    <div frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width:100%; height: auto; margin-bottom: 0px;" id="helpDiv">
    </div>
<iframe src="$*WS_BLOCKOPTION_PAGE*$*WS_SESSIONID*$" name="ws_blockoption" 
        frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width:100%; height: auto;">
        <p>To enable further options, view this page with a browser that supports iframes</p>
    padding: 2px 0px;">
        <div style="clear: both; overflow: hidden; height:1px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> </div> <![endif]-->
<div id="light" class="white_content"></div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this copied straight from your source?

Comment: yes and no, this is the intended script I want to put into the page

Comment: what happens when you run this?

Comment: Looks like we all spotted the same stuff lol

Comment: Ok so I see that error, however my default message isn't even showing up, which should be "No Block message help." This is my troubleshooting message, so there seems to be errors elsewhere as well.

Comment: The escaping lines --.location="'\\"mailto:-- --Thank you."'\\"></p>\-- have been corrected, now it isn't my default case.

Comment: Can you confirm what blockreason is actually being returned before your switch?

Comment: This Websense category is filtered: <b>Uncategorized</b>.
or
This Websense category is filtered: <b>Parked Domain</b>.
or
"other"

Comment: I just added a little more to my answer. There is a problem with your getElementById. See answer for more..

Comment: I have added the <div tag for explanation/reference.

Comment: I think you need in install Firefox and Firebug. this will tell you the problem. I guarantee the switch works and the problem is with your div. Get rid of scrolling and frameborder attributes for a start

Comment: either an issue with the div or with the [$*WS_BLOCKREASON*$] variable. have you tried spitting an alert out before the switch?

Comment: the variable that is passed populates elsewhere as indicated by $*WS_URL*$. I have confirmed this is passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead. You have some incorrect escaping going on...

The part in particular is around your onClick in the first line of the case

```
 case 'This Websense category is filtered: <b>Uncategorized</b>.':
    document.getElementById('helpDiv').innerHTML='<p style="margin-left: 10px">Help:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Submit UNCATEGORIZED website to Websense" onClick="parent.location=\'mailto:suggest@websense.com?subject=Uncategorized Website&body=Please review and correctly categorize the website that is listed below:%0A%0A' + $*WS_URL*$ + '%0A%0AThank you.\'"></p>\
    <hr />\
    <p style="margin-left: 64px">Clicking on the above button will open your mail client to send an e-mail to Websense for recategorization of the above site.</p>\
    <p style="margin-left: 64px">You will receive a confirmation e-mail and a case number from Websense indicating your request is proccessing.</p>\
    <p style="margin-left: 64px">Please note the response time for your request will vary. Allow to three to four (3-4) hours for updates to take effect once approved.</p>\
    <p style="margin-left: 64px">If you have any questions, please contact SOLV at <a href=tel:+18772097658>+1 877 209 7658<a/> or <a href=http://solv:8093/CAisd/pdmweb.exe?OP=JUST_GRONK_IT+HTMPL=about.htmpl target="_blank">this link.</a></p>';
break;
```

**UPDATE:**

Having just had a play in jsFiddle I have come to the conclusion that your reference to helpDiv is invalid..

If you replace all of these with some alerts your switch will reach the default. It's dying because there is something wrong with your getElementById. Maybe the element doesn't have the ID helpDiv?

Here is a well and truly stripped down version

http://jsfiddle.net/5wvC3/

Here is another fiddle - and update on the last one, showing that the code mostly works. You deff have an issue with your HTML

http://jsfiddle.net/5wvC3/1/

Comment: The escaping lines  --.location="'\\"mailto:--   --Thank you."'\\"></p>\--

Comment: lol. I thought I was editing my code - and I removed it after I realised that. :)

Comment: ah, gotcha :) no worries. Don't mind edits, just couldn't see it lol

Comment: I don't think you have confirmed enough. In your function above, just after setting your blockReason you need to confirm blockReason is set. As in my jsFiddle above, your switch works. It's either blockReason is erroneous or that your getElementById is playing up. Install Firebug on Firefox and run it.

Comment: The issue initially was resolved, by errors in the breaks. The secondary issue was the call to document.getElementById('helpDiv').innerHTML did not work. I changed to document.write(), all is well.

Answer (score 0):

You've escaped improperly on this line:

```
    document.getElementById('helpDiv').innerHTML='<p style="margin-left: 10px">Help:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Submit UNCATEGORIZED website to Websense" onClick="parent.location="'\\"mailto:suggest@websense.com?subject=Uncategorized Website&body=Please review and correctly categorize the website that is listed below:%0A%0A$*WS_URL*$%0A%0AThank you."'\\"></p>
```

It should be (after onClick):

```
"parent.location=\'mailto:suggest@websense.com?subject=Uncategorized Website&body=Please review and correctly categorize the website that is listed below:%0A%0A' + $*WS_URL*$ + '%0A%0AThank you.\'"></p>\
```

A fiddle with the escapes corrected: http://jsfiddle.net/3UxCc/
It works.

**Edit:**
It looks like your `$*WS` variables are markers. In this case you're assigning `blockReason` to something, but unless your WebSense variable contains quotes (it doesn't btw), then you're assignment looks something like:

```
var blockReason = other;
```

Since there are no quotes around it, it believes that `other` is a variable not a string literal. You need to enclose this in quotes like:

```
var blockReason = '$*WS_BLOCKREASON*$';
```

This will establish it as a string literal that the switch will be able to use. Anything else will be a bad variable that will throw an error.

Comment: Ok so I see that error, however my default message isn't even showing up, which should be "No Block message help." This is my troubleshooting message, so there seems to be errors elsewhere as well.

Comment: @user1058442: Have you corrected the escaping issues? Because until you've done that this script won't parse at all.

Comment: @user1058442: I've posted a fiddle with the escapes corrected. Your code works. If you're still having trouble then your problem is being generated by code you have not shared with us. Potentially with your javascript variable.

Comment: @user1058442: I think I understand why. Edit to follow shortly.

Comment: I think the error is now tied to websense and its variables, how they are called.